# AWS EC2 file written but can't see anything in the folder - Spring boot java application

Tags: java, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I see that my file was written from the logs :

writing to :/home/ubuntu/s3/landing-pages/landing-page-report_2018-02-05.csv
isFileCreated :true
File was  written

But when I went into EC2 to look for the file, I don't see it listed. It is a spring boot application and deployed using docker image. I double and triple checked the folder path and everything.

Could someone please shed light on this? I am new to AWS

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching EC2 using find command, move to the root folder and try

```
find /home -name landing-page-report_2018-02-05.csv
```

or

```
find /home -name *.csv
```